# How to subscribe redis key space event with spring

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

### My Environment

- Mac Ventura 13.6.3
- Temurin 17
- SpringBoot 3.2.1
- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis
- redis cluster running on local machine. (localhost: 7001, localhost: 7002, localhost: 7003

### What I want to do

I want to receive expire event from redis cluster with spring.

### What I did

I connected to cluster, and expired a key

```
CONFIG SET notify-keyspace-events Ex

SET hi 123
EXPIRE hi 3
```

### My (java) code

Configuration

```java
package kr.co.yogiyo.payo.infrastructure.temporal;

import io.lettuce.core.ReadFrom;
import kr.co.yogiyo.payo.infrastructure.temporal.service.RedisExpireEventService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisConnectionDetails;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisNode;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.PatternTopic;
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

  private final RedisConnectionDetails redisConnectionDetails;

  @Bean
  public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisConnectionDetails.Cluster cluster = redisConnectionDetails.getCluster();
    RedisClusterConfiguration clusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration();
    for (RedisConnectionDetails.Node node : cluster.getNodes()) {
      clusterConfiguration.addClusterNode(new RedisNode(node.host(), node.port()));
    }

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig =
        LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED).build();

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(clusterConfiguration, clientConfig);
  }

  @Bean
  RedisMessageListenerContainer keyExpirationListenerContainer(
      RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, RedisExpireEventService redisExpireEventService) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    listenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    listenerContainer.addMessageListener(
        redisExpireEventService, new PatternTopic("__keyevent@*__:expired"));
    return listenerContainer;
  }
}
```

the service

```java
package kr.co.yogiyo.payo.infrastructure.temporal.service;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.Message;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RedisExpireEventService implements MessageListener {
  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {
    System.out.println("Message received: " + message.toString());
  }
}
```

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  main:
    banner-mode: off
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson:
    property-naming-strategy: SNAKE_CASE
  data:
    redis:
      host: ${PAYO_REDIS_MASTER_HOST:localhost}
      port: ${PAYO_REDIS_MASTER_PORT:7002}
      cluster:
        nodes: ${PAYO_REDIS_REPLICATION_NODES:localhost:7001,localhost:7002,localhost:7003}
```

spring runs well, but nothing happens when key expired.
(I set breakpoint and ran with debug mode, still nothing happens)

### Working python code

I tried with python, it worked like charm... I want to subscribe the event with spring.

```py
import redis


def main():
    # Connect to Redis
    r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=7002, db=0)

    # Subscribe to the '__keyevent@0__:expired' channel
    pubsub = r.pubsub()
    pubsub.psubscribe('__keyevent@*__:expired')

    # Start listening for messages
    for message in pubsub.listen():
        print("something expired! ", message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
something expired!  {'type': 'psubscribe', 'pattern': None, 'channel': b'__keyevent@*__:expired', 'data': 1}
something expired!  {'type': 'pmessage', 'pattern': b'__keyevent@*__:expired', 'channel': b'__keyevent@0__:expired', 'data': b'hi'}
```

could you guys let me know what am I missing in my java code?